# Error PHP undefined constant

Tags: php, mysql, array, mysqli, php7

soy un novato en PHP y estoy haciendo una aplicación que lee los registros de una base de datos, y los convierte en objetos de tipo **Evento**. Después introduce estos Eventos en un array para posteriormente mostrarlos en una tabla.

La aplicación, aparentemente funciona, pero me lanza estas advertencias:

> Warning: Use of undefined constant ID - assumed 'ID' (this will throw
> an Error in a future version of PHP) in
> E:\Xampp\htdocs\PHP\Eventos\Funks.php on line 13
>
> Warning: Use of undefined constant Descripcion - assumed 'Descripcion'
> (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in
> E:\Xampp\htdocs\PHP\Eventos\Funks.php on line 13
>
> Warning: Use of undefined constant Tipo - assumed 'Tipo' (this will
> throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in
> E:\Xampp\htdocs\PHP\Eventos\Funks.php on line 13
>
> Warning: Use of undefined constant Timestamp - assumed 'Timestamp'
> (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in
> E:\Xampp\htdocs\PHP\Eventos\Funks.php on line 13
>
> Warning: Use of undefined constant Pos - assumed 'Pos' (this will
> throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in
> E:\Xampp\htdocs\PHP\Eventos\Funks.php on line 13

Y así con unas cuantas variables mas.

El asunto es que no las defino porque no son variables o constantes como dice la advertencia, son partes clave-valor de un array (que es el resultado de una query mysql convertida en array).

Este es el bloque de código que hace saltar el error:

```
function leerEventos(){
    global $eventosDBc;
    $evArray = [];
    $evs = $eventosDBc->rDB();
    while($fila= mysqli_fetch_array($evs)){
        $evento= new Evento($fila[ID],$fila[Descripcion], 
                $fila[Tipo], 
                $fila[Timestamp], 
                $fila[Pos], 
                $fila[Profundidad], 
                $fila[Temp_agua], 
                $fila[Sal], 
                $fila[Fluor], 
                $fila[Conductividad], 
                $fila[Temp_aire], 
                $fila[Humedad], 
                $fila[Pres_atmos], 
                $fila[Vel_med_viento]);
        array_push($evArray, $evento);
    }
    return $evArray;   
}
```

**Que puedo hacer para solucionarlo? o al menos, para que no aparezcan los warnings encima del contenido de la propia web.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Si `$fila` es un array entonces esos índices van entre comillas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

debes agregar las comillas en los nombres de los campos

```
 $evento= new Evento($fila['ID'],$fila['Descripcion'], 
                $fila['Tipo'], 
                $fila['Timestamp'], 
                $fila['Pos'], 
                $fila['Profundidad'], etc.
```